# Android Widget RemoteViewsFactory

Tags: android, list, widget

I have written RemoteViewsFactory, it has two types of layouts, but i need onClick for only one of them. I've used the tutorial from https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget but it doesn't work.

Though I cannot copy my code, I can say that my layout, that needs onClick uses TextView, ImageView, LinearLayout and RelativeLayout. Does anyone could point me to right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my error, it seems I've set pendingIntentTemplate, but as parameter gave a wrong id. Now other question arises: if I have list in my widget with two different views, is there a way that the listener would be active only for exact view type?

Answer (score 0):

When iterating the widgets ids or in the getViewAt(position) method from RemoteViewsFactory you can simply avoid setting the listener based on your criteria